# Swift Segue not working

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a school project to make a swift app. I'm very new to swift and trying to pass data through the segue from a tableview to another view.
Here is the project file [Download Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwi-zSJ8EtE3Y2FnZG5ZU0dGVGc/view?usp=sharing).

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "PopularDetails" {
            let detailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailsViewController
            let selectedIndexPath = popularTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            detailsViewController.shots = shots[selectedIndexPath.row]
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What's your question? What problem are you having?

Comment: sorry forgot to post that. im getting 'NSIndexPath?' does not have a member named 'row' error.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs here

Comment: yes but it breaks once you got to the details screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.indexPathForSelectedRow() returns an optional. You have to unwrap it, before you can access its properties. Try:

```
let selectedIndexPath = popularTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
detailsViewController.shots = shots[selectedIndexPath!.row]
```

(see the exclamationmark)

Comment: Thanks for the reply gutenmorgenuhu. Im now getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Im guessing my data isn't formatted correctly?

Comment: The problem is, that you want to fire the segue when "View more" is tapped. But this does NOT select the row and .indexPathForSelectedRow() is nil.
When you select the row, and after that, you click "View more". Everything is fine.

You could get rid of the view more, and fire the segue when selecting the row. You can accomplish that in storyboard by ctrl-dragging a new segue from PopularCell to the Details ViewController. From then on, the segue performs correctly when selecting the row (and not "View more")

Answer (score 0):

Although @gutenmorgenuhu is correct, it's probably better practice to use:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PopularDetails" {
        if let detailsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController {
            if let selectedIndexPath = popularTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                detailsViewController.shots = shots[selectedIndexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
}
```